# swift: SKSpriteNode not rotating in update function

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I'm trying to rotate a bone image which is a SKSpriteNode. I created it and on update, I tried running a SKAction which would rotate it. This doesn't do anything. I even tried to decrease the zRotation each time on update by 10 degrees and still nothing happened. I'm sure that the application is not frozen as when I do a println on update, text keeps rolling. Also, other parts of the app are responding. Its just the bone thats not rotating.

Code:

Declaration on start of class

```
let bone = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bone")
let rotateBone = SKAction.rotateByAngle(30, duration: 1)
```

Setting up at didMoveToView

```
bone.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
bone.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
bone.zRotation = CGFloat(arc4random())

self.addChild(bone)
```

Attempting to rotate

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
    bone.runAction(rotateBone)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-running the action on every update (every frame):

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
    bone.runAction(rotateBone)
}
```

Actions run over time. Run it once and let it do its job. Restarting it repeatedly will only replace the previous action and essentially reset it.

Comment: That's not exactly right because when I did bone.zRotation-=10, it didn't rotate either.

Comment: does bone have physics enabled?

Comment: No. Tho code I posted is everything affecting the bone node

Comment: Does the initial zRotation rotate the sprite? I'm not familiar with swift, perhaps bone is nil and bone.runAction simply ignored but if I'm not mistaken trying to run a nil object's function is an error in Swift (unlike in Objc).

Comment: Note: the rotation is in radians, not degrees.

Comment: The first zRotation random setting actually rotates the bone, but then it doesn't rotate as it should